# How to add decimals with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have this if statement:

```
 if (price % 10 > 5) {
        newPrice = floor(price / 10) * 10 + 9.95;
    } elseif (price % 10 <= 5) {
        newPrice = floor(price / 10) * 10 + 5.95;
    }
```

Do i use `parseInt` on 5.95?  This works in PHP but i'm converting to JQuery and wondering if i have to make any changes?

I tried this with no luck

```
if (selectprice % 10 > 5) {
   selectprice = parseFloat(floor(selectprice / 10)) *  parseInt(10) + parseFloat(9.95);
} elseif (selectprice % 10 <= 5) {
    selectprice = parseFloat(floor(selectprice / 10)) * parseInt(10) + parseFloat(5.95);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Math.floor() instead of floor(). I don't think you need to make any other changes.

```
if (selectprice % 10 > 5) {
      selectprice = Math.floor(selectprice / 10) * 10 + 9.95;
} else if (selectprice % 10 <= 5) {
      selectprice = Math.floor(selectprice / 10) * 10 + 5.95;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it broke the script.  I commented out `selectprice=...` .  Something in the If brackets is breaking the code.. is it the modulus?

Comment: @user892134 I had missed a space between "else" and "if". Corrected now.